# NG build - node errors

Tags: node.js, angular

I have installed node_modules using this command:

```
npm install --force
```

Now I am running ng build and getting the following:

> Error: node_modules/@types/prosemirror-model/index.d.ts:1132:40 -
> error TS2709: Cannot  use namespace 'OrderedMap' as a type.
>
> 1132     nodes: { [name in N]: NodeSpec } | OrderedMap;
> ~~~~~~~~~~ Error: node_modules/@types/prosemirror-model/index.d.ts:1139:41 - error
> TS2709: Cannot  use namespace 'OrderedMap' as a type.
>
> 1139     marks?: { [name in M]: MarkSpec } | OrderedMap |
> null | undefined;
> ~~~~~~~~~~ Error: node_modules/@types/prosemirror-schema-list/index.d.ts:44:40 - error
> TS2709:  Cannot use namespace 'OrderedMap' as a type.
>
> 44     nodes: { [name in N]: NodeSpec } | OrderedMap,
> ~~~~~~~~~~ Error: node_modules/@types/prosemirror-schema-list/index.d.ts:47:81 - error
> TS2709:  Cannot use namespace 'OrderedMap' as a type.
>
> 47 ): { [name in (N | "ordered_list" | "bullet_list" | "list_item")]:
> NodeSpec } |  OrderedMap;

Not sure I understand a reason for these errors. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: You might explain why you felt the need to force it. Those conditions may be relevant.

Comment: See https://github.com/ProseMirror/prosemirror/issues/1326.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're flagging me for that. Update your question post.

Comment: You'd do well to update your post title, also. It's quite vague, which results in people like me, who have no idea how to fix your problem, having to wander in to see what you're on about. A clear, specific title question gets you more help and wastes less of my time. See [ask].